# Creating an image for UITabBarController tab - iPhone Dev

Tags: iphone, tabs, controller, icons

Im trying to create a PNG file (thats what I assume the file extension should be) to create an icon for the tab controller.  Here is a picture of what I mean..

http://www.ispazio.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/IMG_0036.png

I tried creating it in Photoshop, saving it as PNG, clearing the background, trying interlaced versions but all I get are big blobs and blocks when I try to import it in the app.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some helpful tutorials:

- http://osmorphis.blogspot.com/2009/02/tab-bar-icons-part-1_4115.html
- http://osmorphis.blogspot.com/2009/03/tab-bar-icons-part-2.html
- http://area72.ro/iphone/iphone-tab-bar-icons.html

Answer (score 0):

you have to use this type of image

[image: This image]

in your tab bar